# Showing Android Permission while in Splash Screen

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, splash-screen

I'm using React Native Platform. What I want is while in the Splash Screen there will pop up a dialog that it says "Please enable the Location" and a button of "Okay"  if they are not opening the Location/GPS the button will be disable until it open the location/gps. When they can tap the "Okay" button because the GPS/Location is enabled the Splash Screen will not hide and navigate to the Home Screen.

My code here is incorrect. I will just post it here.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.requestLocationPermission()
    SplashScreen.hide();
}

requestLocationPermission = () => {
    try{
        const granted = PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                title: 'Location Permission',
                message: 'You must to accept this to make it work.'
            }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("Permission accepted")
        } else {
            console.log("Permission Denied.")
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#4f6d7a" />
            <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler} />
            <UsersMap userLocation={this.state.userLocation} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: What package are you using for your Splash Screen?

Comment: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen